# jQuery - I am not able to bind a function to autonomous function

Tags: javascript, jquery

On click on check box, I am initating a autonomous function, by parallel i am adding a bind event ("keyup") to the same function, but it is not working. and i am not able to send the parameter as well.. what is the correct approach to handle this..?

here is my function :

```
var validateAltName = (function (info) {
    var altName = $.trim(altInput.value);
    console.log(altName); //only one time i am getting, not on keyup..
    if (!altName) {
        altInput.select();
        return;
    }

}());
$(altInput).on("keyup", validateAltName); //is there a way to send parameter?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a function and immediately invoking it, therefore nothing is actually assigned into the variable validateAltName - it remains undefined since that is the return value of the function.

```
var validateAltName = (function (info) {
    var altName = $.trim(altInput.value);
    console.log(altName); //only one time i am getting, not on keyup..
    if (!altName) {
        altInput.select();
        return; // return 'undefined', which gets assigned to validateAltName
    }
    // if you fall off the end, it also returns 'undefined'
}()); // this _calls_ the function
```

Remove the surrounding parentheses and the trailing ()

```
var validateAltName = function (info) { // no opening paren
    var altName = $.trim(altInput.value);
    console.log(altName); //only one time i am getting, not on keyup..
    if (!altName) {
        altInput.select();
        return;
    }

}; // no () parens or closing )
```

**EDIT:** If you want to send parameters to this function when the event occurs, you can include an anonymous function in the handler that invokes it:

```
// instead of
$(altInput).on("keyup", validateAltName); //is there a way to send parameter?
// you can use
$(altInput).on("keyup", function(e) {
    // by using .call() instead of direct invocation () you can preserve 'this'
    validateAltName.call(this, parm1, parm2);
}); //is there a way to send parameter?
```

Comment: you are correct, but even before the keyup, i am looking for the function called.. and any idea to pass the parameters..? But thanks for your answers with explanations.

Answer (score 1):

You are executing your function and just storing the result to the variable. Change your code to this

```
var validateAltName = function (info) {
    var altName = $.trim(altInput.value);
    console.log(altName); //only one time i am getting, not on keyup..
    if (!altName) {
        altInput.select();
        return;
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var validateAltName = function (info) {
    var altName = $.trim(altInput.value);
    console.log(altName); //only one time i am getting, not on keyup..
    if (!altName) {
        altInput.select();
        return;
    }
};
$(altInput).on("keyup", validateAltName);
```